# asp.net mvc serialize() returns empty in controller's model

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

snippet of my `cshtml`:

```
@model Models.ClockingInformationViewModel
<form id="clocking-form">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Time in</label>
                            <div class="input-group date form_datetime">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Attendance.Time01In, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", size = "16" })

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Job code</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Attendance.Time01InJob, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ClockingInformation(ClockingInformationViewModel model)
{
    return null;
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ClockingInformationViewModel
{
    public Attendance Attendance { get; set; }
    public List<Clock> ClockingLocations { get; set; }
}
```

In my javascript, I have this:

```
function saveClockingInformation() {
    var data = $("#clocking-form").serialize();
    $.post($("#clocking-info-url").val(), { model: data });
}
```

When I set a break point in my controller, `ClockingInformationViewModel model` property is null.

When I did `serializeArray()` instead of `serialize()`, `ClockingInformationViewModel model` isn't null, but the property `Attendance` is.

I'm sure it's some silly mistake that I've over looked.

Any insights?

Comment: It just needs to be `$.post($("#clocking-info-url").val(), data);` (data is already the serialized object)

Comment: Did you checked your html output ? If your form elements not has 'name' attribute .serialize() won't generate a request payload for your inputs

Comment: @CihanUygun, the `TextBoxFor()` method generates the correct `name` attributes.

Comment: @StephenMuecke your suggestion worked. May I know why this is the case? It seems the only difference is that I specified the parameter name. That should not affect the way the data is serialize, or does it?

Comment: Yes it does matter. When you serialize the form its posting back `Attendance.Time01In=someValue&Attendance.Time01InJob=anotherValue. The `DefaultModelBinder` first initializes an instance of your model and searches the form data for matches which works (but using `{ model: data }` wont)

Answer (score 2):

Your `var data = $("#clocking-form").serialize();` line of code is already serializing your form to an object, so the code needs to be

```
function saveClockingInformation() {
    var data = $("#clocking-form").serialize();
    $.post($("#clocking-info-url").val(), data);
}
```

Which sends the form data as

```
Attendance.Time01In=someValue&Attendance.Time01InJob=anotherValue
```

whereas your current implementation using `{ model: data }` sends the form data as

```
model[Attendance.Time01In]=someValue&model[Attendance.Time01InJob]=anotherValue
```

which has no relationship to your model, hence binding fails.

Side note: Your use of `$("#clocking-info-url").val()` suggests you putting the url in to a hidden input. Instead, use

```
var url = '@Url.Action("yourAction", "yourController")',
$.post($(url, data);
```

or if you have generated the form using `Html.BeginForm()`, then use

```
var form = $("#clocking-form");
var url = form.attr('action');
$.post($(url, data);
```